# Polymer observable object in dom-repeat not getting update

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer

I'm trying to display an object that contains array in a dom-repeat.
The data structure is as following:
answerObject: {firstQuestion: ["one", "two"],
               secondQuestion: ["three", "four"]}

I'm using computed binding in a nested dom-repeat to convert the object to array, and then use another dom-repeat to display content of the array.

```
  <ul>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_makeArray(answerObject)]]" as="question">
      <li>[[question.key]]</li>

      <ul>
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[question.listOfAnswer]]" as="answer">
              <li>[[answer]]</li>
          </template>
      </ul>
 </template>
```

I created the answerObject property as following:

```
  answerObject: {    
     type: Object,
     notify: true,
     value: {firstQuestion: ["one", "two", "three"], 
             secondQuestion: ["four","five"] },
     observer: '_answerChanged'   
  },
```

I tried all different ways to observe the object or the array, and none triggers the function '_answerChanged' nor '_makeArray'.

```
   /* mutating object and then notifyPath */
   this.set('answerObject.firstQuestion', ["newone"]);
   this.notifyPath('answerObject.firstQuestion');

   /* mutating array then notifySplices */
   this.push('answerObject.secondQuestion',"six");
   this.notifySplices('answerObject.secondQuestion', [
     {index:3, removed: [], addedCount: 1, object: _this.answerObject.secondQuestion, type:'splice'}
   ]);

   /* dirty check */
   var array = this.answerObject.firstQuestion;
   this.answerObject.firstQuestion=[];
   this.answerObject.firstQuestion = array;
```

Any suggestion what do I miss? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a demo fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observer is not triggered, because your scenario is not supported.

As per [official documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#work-with-arrays):

> **Primitive array items are not supported**. This is because primitives (like number, **string** and boolean values) with the same
>   value are represented by the same object.

The currently recommended workaround (also stated in my previous link) is, that you simply wrap your primitive values with a simple object.

So, instead of this:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

You use something like this:

```
[{ value: "one" }, { value: "two" }, { value: "three" }]
```